# Gnome shell reverts to Gnome 2

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-11.10, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I cannot run Gnome 3, only Gnome 2, even though I have gnome-shell installed and set as the default Window Manager.

Here is what I see after I run gnome-shell --replace

> (gnome-shell:3136): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'gnome-shell' received
>   an X Window System error. This probably reflects a bug in the program.
>   The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such
>   operation)'.   (Details: serial 147 error_code 1 request_code 155
>   minor_code 19)   (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported
>   asynchronously;    that is, you will receive the error a while after
>   causing it.    To debug your program, run it with the --sync command
>   line    option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful 
>   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error()
>   function.)

How do I fix this? I am running Ubuntu 11.10. I cannot upgrade.

Comment: How is this programming related? Try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: From the FAQ: "What kind of questions can I ask here? ...software tools commonly used by programmers...
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession..."

As you can see, I have fulfilled at least one, if not two, criteria for a valid question.

Comment: Sorry, I agree that it doesn't fit here. Questions about writing extensions for Gnome Shell are appropriate, but troubleshooting running it is not. Luckily there are at least two other Stack Exchange sites you can try! superuser.com and askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some years ago, and I fixed it updating Catalyst drivers. Here's the link: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/fglrx-driver/fglrx-driver_12-6+point-3_amd64.deb